# Use query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, nested

I´m having issues with the following query. I have two tables; Table Orderheader and table Bought. The first query I execute gives me, for example, two dates. Based on these two dates, I need to find Production data AND, based on the production data, I need to find the Bought data, and combine those data together. Lets say I do the following:

```
Select Lotdate From Orderheader where orhsysid = 1
```

This results in two rows: '2019-02-05' and '2019-02-04'. Now I need to do two things: I need two run two queries using this result set. The first one is easy; use the dates returned and get a sum of column A like this:

```
Select date, SUM(Amount) from Orderheader where date = Sales.date() [use the two dates here]
```

The second one is slighty more complicated, I need to find the last day where something has been bought based on the two dates. Production is everyday so Productiondate=Sales.date()-1. But Bought is derived from Productionday and is not everyday so for every Productionday it needs to find the last Boughtday. So I can't say where date = Orderheader.date. I need to do something like:

```
Select date, SUM(Amount) 
FROM Bought 
WHERE date = (
    SELECT top 1 date 
    FROM Bought 
    WHERE date < Orderheader.date)
```

But twice, for both the dates I got. 
This needs to result in 1 table giving me:

```
Bought.date, Bought.SUM(AMOUNT), Orderheader.date, Orderheader.SUM(AMOUNT)
```

All based on the, possible multiple, Lotdate(s) I got from the first query from Sales table.

I've been struggling with this for a moment now, using joins and nested queries but I can't seem to figure it out!

Example sample:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,ORF.orfDate) as Productiedatum, SUM(orlQuantityRegistered) as 'Aantal'
FROM OrderHeader ORH
LEFT JOIN OrderFrame ORF ON ORH.orhFrameSysID = ORF.orfSysID
LEFT JOIN OrderLine ORL ON ORL.orhSysID = ORH.orhSysID
LEFT JOIN Item ON Item.itmSysID = ORL.orlitmSysID
where CONVERT(date,ORF.orfDate) IN
  (
      SELECT DISTINCT(CONVERT(date, Lot.lotproductiondate)) as Productiedatum
      FROM OrderHeader ORH
      LEFT JOIN Registration reg ON reg.regorhSysID = ORH.orhSysID
      LEFT JOIN StockRegistration stcreg ON stcreg.stcregRegistrationSysID = reg.regSysID
      LEFT JOIN Lot ON Lot.lotSysID = stcregSrclotSysID 
      WHERE ORH.orhSysID = 514955
      AND regRevokeRegSysID IS NULL
      AND stcregSrcitmSysID = 5103
  )
AND ORL.orlitmSysID = 5103
AND orldirSysID = 2
AND NOT orlQuantityRegistered IS NULL
GROUP BY Orf.orfDate
```

Sample output:

```
Productiedatum  Aantal
2019-02-05       20
2019-02-06       20
```

Here I used a nested subquery to get the results from 'Production' (orderheader) because I just can use date = date. I'm struggling with the Sales part where I need to find the last date(s) and use those dates in the Sales table to get the sum of that date.

Expected output:

```
Productiedatum  Aantal Boughtdate  Aantal
2019-02-04       20    2019-02-01  55
2019-02-05       20    2019-02-04  60
```

Comment: You can't reference `Production.date` in your query with the subquery; the object `production` isn't referenced in any of your `FROM` statements. Could you post some sample data and expect results please? I'm *guessing* you need to store the values from your first query into variables and then use those values, based on the description we have.

Comment: share sample data and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Production') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Production
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Bought') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Bought

CREATE table #Production(R_NO int,ProductionDate datetime,ProductionAmount float)
CREATE table #Bought(R_NO int,Boughtdate datetime,Boughtamount float)

insert into #Production(ProductionDate,ProductionAmount,R_NO)
select p.date ProductionDate,sum(Amount) ProductionAmount,row_number()over (order by p.date) R_NO 
from Production P
join Sales  s on p.date=S.date-1   
where orhsysid=1
group by p.date



declare @loop int,@ProdDate datetime
select @loop =max(R_NO) from #Production
while (1<=@loop)
begin

select @ProdDate=ProductionDate from #Production where r_no=@loop

insert into #Bought(Boughtdate,Boughtamount,R_NO)
select Date,Sum(Amount),@loop R_NO from Bought where date=(
select max(date) from bought B
where B.Date<@ProdDate)
group by Date

set @loop=@loop-1
end

select ProductionDate,ProductionAmount,Boughtdate,Boughtamount from #Bought B 
join #Production p on B.R_NO=P.R_NO
```

Comment: Beautiful thank you it works. One question, If I execute the query a second time it tells me there is already an object named #production in the database. So I changed it to Declare table

Comment: @vincentkleine edited the script to delete the temp tables if they exists.